# Trivial action in the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I probably don't understand something very basic about Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.

Let $G$ be a group with normal subgroup $N$ and $M$ a $G$-module with trivial action. Then as far as I understand the derivation $d_0$ from the zero row is defined as $m$ goes to the function that sends $g$ to $m-g(m)$. Since the action is trivial I get that this is the zero map. Now, in the computation of the derivation $d_2$ from row 1 to row 0 we need to pull back $d_0$. Does it mean that $d_2$ from row 1 to row 0 is always zero? I've seen several examples that contradict this.

Comment: What is the meaning of $m/g(m)$ in a module??

Comment: I am interested in coefficients in a multiplicative group of a field, so the $M$ is a multiplicative abelian group. Maybe it would be clearer if I wrote m-g(m)